# Error exporting the site field named "HashTags_0"."

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-template, save

I am trying to save a site as template in SharePoint Server 2013 on premises but I keep getting this error:

> Error exporting the site field named "HashTags_0"." ...

I don't see a field named `'HashTags_0'` in site columns.Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the problem was. Even though I don't know what the cause is. When I view the site elements in SharePoint Manager 2013, the HashTag_0 field is there twice with the same GUID.

So I guess that when the export process cant overwrite the field a second time with the same GUID so it chokes.

My solution is to use powershell to delete duplicate fields as follows:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://somesite/someweb

$HashFields =  $web.Fields | Where {$_.Title -like 'HashTags_0'}

  foreach($F in $HashFields)

  {

    $F.Title

    if(!$F.Sealed){$F.delete()}

  }

$web.Update()

$web.Dispose()
```

After this I was able to Save site as template.

I hope this helps